# How do I make imagebutton and navigation view, toolbar and text view adjust to screen size in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, responsive-design, responsive

I want to make all of my design scale to sit nicely in any type of screen size, I have this image button which instead of adjusting according to the screen size it either stays the same or increases its background to fill the whole screen, how do I make it adjust to whatever screen size it is and how do I do this for toolbars and text view as well since I'm trying to also add in a navigation drawer and header. Here is my code:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:background="#6666ff"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:src="@drawable/img1">
            </ImageButton>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#6666ff"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:gravity="bottom">


    <TextView
        android:text="app"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:text="by dev"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```